# Тестирование методов, использующих объекты-свойства.

Tags: юнит-тесты, yii2, phpunit

Всем доброго времени суток!

Вопрос по тестированию, как лучше поступить с таким, например, методом:

```
class Class{
    public function clearImagesCache()
        {
            if($this->owner->getImagesCount()>0){
                foreach($this->owner->getImages() as $img){
                    $img->clearCache();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
 }
```

Мои варианты:

1. создать мок $this->owner и внедрить его в mock объект Class
2. создать методы для Class, в которых вызывать методы owner, и их переопределять в mock объекте

Я еще плохо разбираюсь в этом, хочется услышать как лучше поступить и почему это лучше, чем другие варианты.

Большое спасибо.

**Обновление**

[[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki)

1) "Если мы пойдем на уровень выше, то тут не обязательно применять моки вообще."
Дело в том, что этот класс - поведение в yii2, те если я пойду на уровень выше - мне практически нужно создавать отдельный проект - демо апп, тестриующий модуль с этим поведением. Такой вариант вполне рассматриваю, тк он для меня проще, и результат нужный может дать.

2) "Что до архитектуры: ее надо допиливать." - ага, спасибо!
Но вопрос остается - что лучше, в конструкторе делать `setOwner(OwnerInterface $owner)` и потом использовать везде `$this->owner` или для каждого метода owner создавать метод в this?

```
getImagesCount(){  
    return $this->owner->getImagesCount();   
}
```

3) "И последнее: PHP вообще еще не дорос до серьезных языков с точки зрения архитектуры, но yii - это фрактал плохой архитектуры."

Можешь порекомендовать альтернативы php и в php альтернативы yii? те на что было бы логично  и проще переходить.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> Я еще плохо разбираюсь в этом, хочется услышать как лучше поступить и почему это лучше, чем другие варианты.

95% посетителей этого сайта не знаю слова "мок", из остальных 4/5 ленятся или не имеют времени использовать моки в повседневной разработке.

Что касается юнит-тестирования - оно провдится изолированно и покомпонентно. У нас есть функционал удаления файла, мы его тестируем отдельно; у нас есть функционал получения списка файлов для дуаления, его мы тоже тестируем отдельно; вместе они не тестируются в рамках юнит-тестов.

Если мы пойдем на уровень выше, то тут не обязательно применять моки вообще. Берем виртуальную [файловую систему](https://packagist.org/search/?q=vfs) (лично я использую пакет mikey179/vfsStream, но он не очень удобный, удобных я и не видел), разворачиваем там что хотим, проверяем, что после выполнения кода все подчистилось, как надо. Долго, дорого, как у Лебедева. Я таким образом тестирую один автозагрузчик классов на нахождение файлов.

Если ни один из вариантов не подходит: decoupl'им класс, создаем метод `setOwner(OwnerInterface $owner)`, прокидываем мок, мок возвращает моки класса `Image` с пустым методом `clearCache()`, который должен вызваться ровно один раз на каждом моке (Codeception Stub такое точно умеет, другие mock-библиотеки наверняка тоже).

Что до архитектуры: ее надо допиливать. Изображение не должно управлять своим кэшем, owner вряд ли должен управлять изображениями с целью отредактировать их кэш, сторонний класс тут вообще не при чем. Некий ImageManager должен получать изображения, связанные с пользователем, получать их пути, и кормить CacheManager'у в качестве ключей, по которым нужно дропнуть кэш. Сам owner здесь не участвует. CacheManager не подозревает о механизме получения ключей, ImageManager не представляет, куда его результат пойдет, реюзабилити повышается.

> и внедрить его в mock объект Class

Тестируемый объект лучше не мокать. Мок нам нужен только для того, чтобы подменить зависимости и изолировать таким образом тест от влияния внешних факторов.

> создать методы для Class, в которых вызывать методы owner, и их переопределять в mock объекте

Ноу! Это знатно повысит зависимости в системе, заодно класс почему-то начнет дублировать функционал owner, хотя отношения к этому функционалу не имеет.

И последнее: PHP вообще еще не дорос до серьезных языков с точки зрения архитектуры, но yii - это фрактал плохой архитектуры. Вторая версия, конечно, исправила многие недочеты, но все равно там полно ада и погибели, а написанное практически нельзя переиспользовать, потому что все почему-то должно лежать в одном неймспейсе app и все тут. Результатом, безусловно, будет ровно тот же конфликт имен, который мешал в первой версии. Yii не подчиняется логике и не будет, yii пишется для решения конкретных задач, которые встают вот здесь, без оглядки на то, что может быть нужно. Это хорошо сказывается на быстрой раработке простых приложений, но по мере усложнения градус ада растет экспоненциально.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Costa, после появления трейтов поведения не нужны в принципе (хотя они и до этого были не нужны, нужна была человеческая система событий). Уровень выше - это системные тесты, которые проверяют функционал системы целиком, и поднимать тестовое приложение, работая с ним только снаружи - это нормально.

> или для каждого метода owner создавать метод в this?

Я уже писал - ни в коем случае.

> Альтернативы php

По части архитектуры - java и c#. C++ тоже наверняка даст фору всем окружающи, но у него не настолько легкочитаемый синтаксис, как у предыдущих двух

Comment: > Альтернативы yii

Symfony. Laravel и Phalcon смотрел мельком, и они не блещут, честно говоря (хоть работа сделана и большая).